# Crop a surface view in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview, crop

Here's what I need:

I have a Surface view that has a square (image view) on top of it. I need to capture an image, and crop out the area that was visible only within the square.

This code gives me decent results but specific only to some devices:

```
int width=(int)(bitmap.getWidth()*60/100);
int height=(bitmap.getHeight()*100/100); //dont change
bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,150,0, width-55, height);
```

Is there any way I could generalize this code? Is there any other way to get what I need?

**EDIT:** This is how I got it to work-

1. Save the image from the surface view as a bitmap (This is very simple. There are many examples available on the internet that show how to do that)
2. Use this code in a function, and call it after the image is clicked

   ```
   //bitmap is the object where the image is stored
   int width = bitmap.getWidth();
   int height = bitmap.getHeight();

   int left;
   if(width > height){
       left = (width - height)/2;
   }
   else {
       left = (height - width)/2;
   }

   bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,left,0, height, height);
   ```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by: _"fairly decent results but specific only to some devices"_? what is the difference between devices? What is the size of the square and how is ti placed?

Comment: This code works well on xhdpi devices like the Galaxy S3 not on mdpi or ldpi devices

Comment: _"works well"_ I see.. what happens on `mdpi` or `ldpi` devices? crash or no cropping or wrong cropping or what? If your answer is it crops wrongly, then please give an example.. what is the cropping you want and what you get. Currently there is not enough information in your question.. just using generic terms like _"works well"_